# How can I set up routes like /country and /country/city using only Navigo.js?

Tags: javascript, routes, single-page-application

This is the code on my router.js file:

```
window.router = new Navigo("/", { hash: false });

//This function loads css files
function loadStyleSheet(path) {

    //Get any previous style sheet
    const existingStylesheet = document.getElementById('dynamic-stylesheet');

    //If there is an existing style sheet, delete it
    if (existingStylesheet) {
        existingStylesheet.remove();
    }

    //Create a new style sheet with the provided path
    const link = document.createElement('link');
    link.id = 'dynamic-stylesheet';
    link.rel = 'stylesheet';
    link.href = path;

    //Add the new style sheet to the head of the document
    document.head.appendChild(link);
}

//This function loads html files and an array of JS files
function loadContent(htmlFile, jsFiles, into) {
    console.log(`Loading HTML from: ${htmlFile}`);
    console.log(`Loading JS from: ${jsFiles}`);

    // Load HTML
    fetch(htmlFile)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(html => {
            document.querySelector(into).innerHTML = html;

            // Load JS sequentially
            const loadJS = (index) => {
                if (index >= jsFiles.length) {
                    return Promise.resolve();
                }

                return new Promise(resolve => {
                    const script = document.createElement('script');
                    script.src = jsFiles[index];
                    script.onload = () => {
                        console.log(`The JS file ${jsFiles[index]} has been loaded`);
                        resolve(loadJS(index + 1));
                    };
                    document.body.appendChild(script);
                });
            };

            return loadJS(0);
        });
}


// Set up the router
router
  .on({
    '/': () => {
      router.navigate('/planet'); //root
    },
    '/planet': () => {
      loadStyleSheet('resources/styles/mainstyles.css');
      loadContent("planet.html", ["./resources/js/planet.js"], "#app");
    },
    '/moon': () => {
      loadStyleSheet('resources/styles/mainstyles.css');
      loadContent("moon.html", ["./resources/js/moon.js"], "#app");
    },
    '/stars': () => {
      loadStyleSheet('resources/styles/mainstyles.css');
      loadContent("stars.html", ["./resources/js/stars.js"], "#app");
    },
    '/country': () => {
      loadStyleSheet('resources/styles/otherstyles.css');
      loadContent("country.html", ["./resources/js/country.js"], "#app");
    },
    '/city': () => {
      loadStyleSheet('resources/styles/otherstyles.css');
      loadContent("city.html", ["./resources/js/city.js"], "#app");
    }
  })
  .notFound(() => {
    router.navigate('/planet');
    loadStyleSheet('resources/styles/mainstyles.css');
    loadContent("planet.html", ["./resources/js/planet.js"], "#app");
  })
  .resolve();
```

On each JS file I already have events being fired when clicking on some buttons, redirecting the user to the specified route, like

```
if (window.router) {
  document.getElementById("moon-button").addEventListener("click", () => {
    window.router.navigate("/moon");
  });
  document.getElementById("stars-button").addEventListener("click", () => {
    window.router.navigate("/stars");
  });
} else {
  console.log("The router object is not available");
}
```

My issue is that I don't know how to make /city a child route of /country, so that when the user gets access to city.html, the url says /country/city. Please, help me, I have read Navigo's documentation (https://github.com/krasimir/navigo/blob/master/DOCUMENTATION.md) and I just can't do it. All of my html files have bootstrap only, so I would like to set up the router only using JS, NOT React Router OR Angular.

This was my attempt:

```
router
  .on({
    '/': () => {
      router.navigate('/planet'); //root
    },
    '/planet': () => {
      loadStyleSheet('resources/styles/mainstyles.css');
      loadContent("planet.html", ["./resources/js/planet.js"], "#app");
    },
    '/moon': () => {
      loadStyleSheet('resources/styles/mainstyles.css');
      loadContent("moon.html", ["./resources/js/moon.js"], "#app");
    },
    '/stars': () => {
      loadStyleSheet('resources/styles/mainstyles.css');
      loadContent("stars.html", ["./resources/js/stars.js"], "#app");
    }
  }).on({
    '/country': () => {
      loadStyleSheet('resources/styles/otherstyles.css');
      loadContent("country.html", ["./resources/js/country.js"], "#app");
    },
    '/country/city': () => {
      loadStyleSheet('resources/styles/otherstyles.css');
      loadContent("city.html", ["./resources/js/city.js"], "#app");
    }
  })
  .notFound(() => {
    router.navigate('/planet');
    loadStyleSheet('resources/styles/mainstyles.css');
    loadContent("planet.html", ["./resources/js/planet.js"], "#app");
  })
  .resolve();
```

which did not work, and I also tried:

```
router
  .on({
    '/': () => {
      router.navigate('/planet'); //root
    },
    '/planet': () => {
      loadStyleSheet('resources/styles/mainstyles.css');
      loadContent("planet.html", ["./resources/js/planet.js"], "#app");
    },
    '/moon': () => {
      loadStyleSheet('resources/styles/mainstyles.css');
      loadContent("moon.html", ["./resources/js/moon.js"], "#app");
    },
    '/stars': () => {
      loadStyleSheet('resources/styles/mainstyles.css');
      loadContent("stars.html", ["./resources/js/stars.js"], "#app");
    },
    '/country': () => {
      loadStyleSheet('resources/styles/otherstyles.css');
      loadContent("country.html", ["./resources/js/country.js"], "#app");
    }
  }).on({
    '/country/city': () => {
      loadStyleSheet('resources/styles/otherstyles.css');
      loadContent("city.html", ["./resources/js/city.js"], "#app");
    }
  })
  .notFound(() => {
    router.navigate('/planet');
    loadStyleSheet('resources/styles/mainstyles.css');
    loadContent("planet.html", ["./resources/js/planet.js"], "#app");
  })
  .resolve();
```

which also did not work.